# How to avoid copy-paste of exceptionness function?

Tags: c#, .net

I have following functionality in few different classes C1, D2, F34:

```
class C1
{
    void SomeFunc
    {
        Statement1();
        Obj = GetObj();
        Statement2(Obj);
    }
    IMyObj Obj{get;private set;}
}

public static class MyObjExt
{
    public static void Statement2(this IMyObj obj)
    {
        ... do validation of 'obj';
        ... throw exception if object state is wrong
    }
}
```

Classes C1, D2, F34 aren't member of same hierarchy.

so I would like to avoid copy paste of them.

I could do something like this:

```
static MyObj MyFunc()
{
  Statement1();
  IMyObj obj = GetObj();
  Statement2(obj);

  return obj;
}
class C1
{
  void SomeFunc
  {
      Obj = MyFunc();
  }
  IMyObj Obj{get;private set;}
}
```

but if "Statement2" function throws an exception obj member will left uninitialized...

How could I avoid copy-paste?

Comment: What do you *want* to happen?

Comment: I want to have 'Obj' property always initialized. Especially, if exception is thrown in 'Statement2'.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  It looks like `Statement1()` and `Statement2()` have nothing to do with the initialization of `Obj` - why have them in the same method?

Comment: What operation does Statement2() perform on the newly-instanced obj? Is it possible to break what you're doing there out into multiple calls?  This is confusingly-factored.

Comment: Statement2 uses Obj. Actually, it validates object state (I will update question)

Comment: @Budda: you're trying to say that when the object would enter an invalid state, you're left with one member uninitialized? Shouldn't you be worrying about the object being in an invalid state? In other news, you should have a more meaningful example. It's hard to give advice when the code can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have a little bit more complicated solution:

```
class Extender
{
    static IMyObj MyFunc(out IMyObj obj)
    {
        Statement1();
        obj = GetObj();
        Statement2(obj);
    }
}

class C1
{
  void SomeFunc
  {
    IMyObj obj=null;
    try
    {
         MyFunc(out obj);
    }
    finally
    {
        Obj = obj;
    }
  }
  IMyObj Obj{get;private set;}
}
```

But I not sure if it will and must work. Is this good or bad approach?

If you think it is good - please vote, if no - please point "why"?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Added 'SomeFunc' implementation after modification.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. Why would you want to guarantee C1.Obj gets initialized, even with an object in an invalid state?

Comment: That is a piece of service. I want to log any error occurred during service method execution. I extract this object from DB using "composite key" and this object will have solid (valid) primary key. I want to use this primary key in log table. Actually, I could use a separate object just in order to store key, but for this example it doesn't matter (I will need to store some information before potential exception can be thrown.

Comment: That won't compile.  Methods can only exist within a class in C#.

Comment: Just add any static class around those 'MyFunc' method... it is not a big deal. My intention was to show an idea. Hope, idea is clear enough